# How to create/match multiple relationships between existing nodes? (by same parameter)

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, neo4j, cypher

I have seen relevant questions on StackOverflow, but guess this one is different.

The actual problem is: How to crate multiply relationship between existing nodes?

I got this code:

```
session
    .run('MATCH(u:TEST { id: $id }) \n' +
        'MATCH(m:TEST { id: 39}) \n' +
        'CREATE(m)-[r:RELATIONSHIP {Quantity: $q}]->(u)\n', {id: 4, q: 4})
    .then(function (result) {
        result.records.forEach(function (record) {
            console.log(record);
        });
        session.close();
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
    });
```

and it's works fine, but crate only one relationship. And it stops working in this case:
`{id: [45, 65, 87], q: 4}`

but there is no any error, the relation doesn't create.

**I solve this problem by this code:**

```
let x = [79, 43, 85];
for (let i = 0; i < x.length; i++)
session
        .run('MATCH(u:TEST { id: $id }), {id: x, q: 4})' +
```

The next problem is: **How to match various nodes by the same parameter `id` but not `<id>`**, for example:

The difference between `id` and `<id>` is that first one, is a custom field made by made, and the second one is native Neo4j field 
(By the way, as you already notice I use `node.js` so could I replace native `<id>` field by value from my custom made `id` via this Cypher query: 
`'CREATE (a:TEST {id: $id, name: $name}) RETURN a'`

```
let x = [79, 43, 85];
let y = [59, 77, 80];

for (let i = 0; i < x.length; i++)

session
  .run('MATCH(u:TEST { id: $id }) \n' +
    'MATCH(m:TEST { id: $id}) \n' + //I want to see array from y here
    'CREATE(m)-[r:RELATIONSHIP {Quantity: $q}]->(u)\n', {id: x, q: 4})
```

Could I use `{id: x, id: y, q: 4}`
`id` twice, or `x` & `y` right in the Cypher query? Or should I re-write it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for [IN operator](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/clauses/where/#where-in-operator).

```
session.run('MATCH(u:TEST) WHERE u.id in $id \n' +
    'MATCH(m:TEST { id: 39}) \n' +
    'CREATE(m)-[r:RELATIONSHIP {Quantity: $q}]->(u)\n', {id: [45, 65, 87], q: 4})
```

Also, to access the internal ID managed by Neo4j you need to use the [id()](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/functions/scalar/#functions-id). This way your current query is not matching by the internal ID since you are not using the `id()` function.

---

**EDIT:**

After some clarification in comments and other answer the query that fits the desired behavior is:

```
match (n1:TEST) where n1.id in $ids1
match (n2:TEST) where n2.id in $ids2
with collect(distinct n1) as x, collect(distinct n2) as y, $qs, range(0,size($qs) - 1) as indexes
unwind indexes as index
with x[index] as start, qs[index] as quantity, y[index] as end
create (start)-[:SHIET {Quantity:quantity}]->(end)
```

Considering that all arrays have the same size (eg. `{ids1: [79, 43, 85], ids2:y[59, 44, 36], qs: [3, 4, 4]}`)

Comment: testing it... btw I'm free to use any Cypher query in `session.run()` am I correct? (so there is no need to rewrite it from original cypher)

Comment: @AlexZeDim I think so. But why are you thinking about rewrite your query? Its not clear to me.

Comment: I don't have so much experience in `Neo4j` as I want, and I remember myself during learning `JS` when I needed to rewrite almost everything with `callback` for `promise`. So I'm still thinking like I'm doing something wrong

Comment: `MATCH(u:TEST) WHERE u.id in $id` isn't working as it should be. Instead of creating 3 TEST relationships `'CREATE(m)-[r:TEST {Quantity: $q}]->(u)\n', {id: [79, 65, 87], q: 4})`
between 45 → 39, 65→ 39, 87 → 39, it makes only **one** relationship between first (45) point and endpoint

Comment: @AlexZeDim are you sure that all 3 nodes exist?

Comment: hm, as for now, it's working fine, but I'd like to test it with point node `id`

Comment: Everything works fine, as for now, but I in my case **[one-to-one] x multiply** `for` cycle perfectly suits my needs. But I guess in **[many-to-many]** using `WHERE` is better. And there is still a difference between then. As for the more: If I use my own field `id` with custom value, (I can't replace it, and I'll using it in the future) can it cause trouble in future, because `neo4j` using it's own `<id>` field? Should I try to merge/place my value (yes, it's unique) to `<id>` or `it's OK` to use both `ids` as they are?

Comment: I don't know if I understand your question completely. But you should not trust in Neo4j internal ID because they can change. Neo4j reuses the internal ID when a node or relationship is deleted. In fact the Neo4j internal id indicates a position of the node / relationship in a file managed by Neo4j graph storage. That is: your application should use your own custom ID to manage nodes and relationships. @AlexZeDim

Comment: @AlexZeDim You can read more [here](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/clauses/match/#get-node-rel-by-id) and [here](https://neo4j.com/blog/dark-side-neo4j-worst-practices/). Alternatively you can use the [GraphAware Neo4j UUID plugin](https://github.com/graphaware/neo4j-uuid) which  assigns a UUID to newly created nodes and relationships in the graph and makes sure nobody can (accidentally or intentionally) change or delete them.

Comment: Yeah, I have read this `UUID` thread 7-10 mins ago. But it's not relevant to my problem, because both ids are fine for me, I just cares about `duplicate` data problem

Answer (score 0):

Ok, actually there is always another way. In my cause I use `for` cycle which helps me to export necessary values from `result` **MongoDB** array to **Neo4j** and create multiply one-to-mane `-relationships->`:

```
let x = [79, 43, 85];
let y = [59, 44, 36];
let q = [3, 4, 4];

 for (let i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    session
        .run('MATCH(u:TEST { id: $id_1 }) \n' +
            'MATCH(m:TEST { id: $id_2}) \n' +
            'CREATE(m)-[r:SHIET {Quantity: $q}]->(u)\n', {id_1: x[i], id_2:y[i], q: q[i]})
        .then(function (result) {
            result.records.forEach(function (record) {
                console.log(record);
            });
            session.close();
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            console.log(error);
        });
}
```

You could use `.map` and `set Maps` or anything JS in this particular case.
As for the more, there is still a difference between execution of this code, and `@Bruno Peres` answer.

Comment: Considering that all arrays have the same size (eg. `{ids1: [79, 43, 85], ids2:y[59, 44, 36], qs: [3, 4, 4]}`) you can do the same work in a single query without a `foreach` this way: `match (n1:TEST) where n1.id in $ids1
match (n2:TEST) where n2.id in $ids2
with collect(distinct n1) as x, collect(distinct n2) as y, $qs, range(0,size($qs) - 1) as indexes
unwind indexes as index
with x[index] as start, qs[index] as quantity, y[index] as end
create (start)-[:SHIET {Quantity:quantity}]->(end)`

Comment: Also, `$ids1` and `$ids2` must exists. And the query is a bit more complicated...

Comment: Could you add this code to your answer up above? It will be very helpful for me and SW community in future.

Comment: sure. Added. Thanks!